# How to create a shapely polygon with a hole?

Tags: python, shapely

Sounds like a simple question, and the [Shapely doc](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Polygon) says all I need to do to create a simple polygon with a hole is to pass two lists of coordinate tuples:

```
exterior = [(2, 8), (7, 8), (7, 3), (2, 3), (2, 8)]
interior = [(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)]
pgn = Polygon(exterior, holes=interior)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_ndim'
```

I also tried passing a Polygon as the interior ring.

```
interior=Polygon([(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)])
pgn = Polygon(exterior, holes=interior)

>>> TypeError: object of type 'Polygon' has no len()
```

What is the correct way to use this constructor? Looks like the `holes` parameter should not be a tuple or a `Polygon`, so what should it be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A polygon can have multiple holes in it, so the `holes` argument is a list of list of coordinate tuples:

```
>>> exterior = [(2, 8), (7, 8), (7, 3), (2, 3), (2, 8)]
>>> interior = [(4, 7), (4, 5), (6, 5), (6, 7), (4, 7)]
```

This fails:

```
>>> pgn = Polygon(exterior, holes=interior)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/rowlings/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 240, in __init__
    ret = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
  File "/home/rowlings/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 506, in geos_polygon_from_py
    N = exemplar._ndim
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_ndim'
```

because `interior` isn't a list of interior polygons, its just one. So make it a list with one member:

```
>>> pgn = Polygon(exterior, holes=[interior])
>>> pgn
<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7fb3639bc250>
```

Docs:

```
The second is an optional unordered sequence of ring-like sequences specifying the interior boundaries or “holes” of the feature.
```

The "source code" links are great working examples of the shapely API, eg this:

```
ext = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)]
int = [(1, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (1, 1), (1.5, 0.5), (1, 0)][::-1]
polygon = Polygon(ext, [int])
```

in https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/polygon.py

Comment: Ah, that's it! Knew I would be missing something simple. I might suggest adding an example to their docs to make it easier for the next person who has this problem.

Comment: The reason why you need `[::-1]` at the end of the `interior` sequence is because ring coordinate pairs should be ordered counter-clockwise while hole sequences should be clockwise.